# Formik is Not Rendering Initial Values

Tags: javascript, reactjs, formik

I am using Formik for form submission in my React Project.

```
const initialValues =
    submittedAssignment !== undefined
      ? {
          comments: submittedAssignment?.comments,
          mk1: mKeys[0],
          mk2: mKeys[1],
          mk3: mKeys[2],
          mk4: mKeys[3],
          mk1Num: submittedAssignment?.mk1Num,
          mk2Num: submittedAssignment?.mk2Num,
          mk3Num: submittedAssignment?.mk3Num,
          mk4Num: submittedAssignment?.mk4Num,
        }
      : {
          comments: "",
          mk1: "",
          mk2: "",
          mk3: "",
          mk4: "",
          mk1Num: 0,
          mk2Num: 0,
          mk3Num: 0,
          mk4Num: 0,
        };

  console.log(initialValues);

return(
<Formik
          initialValues={initialValues}
          validationSchema={Yup.object({
            comments: Yup.string().required(),
            mk1Num: Yup.number().positive().required().max(5),
            mk2Num: Yup.number().positive().required().max(5),
            mk3Num: Yup.number().positive().required().max(5),
            mk4Num: Yup.number().positive().required().max(5),
          })}
          onSubmit={async (values, { setErrors, setSubmitting }) => {
            try {
              values = testFunction(values);
              console.log(values);
              const totalGrade =
                values.mk1Num + values.mk2Num + values.mk3Num + values.mk4Num;
              const response = await updateSubmittedAssignment(
                courseId,
                assignmentId,
                values,
                totalGrade,
                studentId
              );
              if (response.data.data === false)
                setErrors({ err: "Error Submitting. Please contact tech" });
              else {
                setSubmitting(false);
                history.push(
                  `/submittedAssignments/${courseId}/${assignmentId}`
                );
              }
            } catch (error) {
              setErrors({ err: error.message });
            }
          }}
        >
          {({ isSubmitting, submitForm, isValid, errors }) => (
            <Form className="ui form">
              <TextArea
                name="comments"
                placeholder="Enter Comments Here"
                rows={10}                
              />
              <Select
                name="mk"
                placeholder="Select Marking Key"
                options={markingKeys}
                onChange={handleMk}
              />
              <br />
              {mKeys.length > 0 && (
                <Grid>
                  <Grid.Column width={14}>
                    <TextInput name="mk1" id={1} value={mKeys[0]} />
                    <TextInput name="mk2" id={2} value={mKeys[1]} />
                    <TextInput name="mk3" id={3} value={mKeys[2]} />
                    <TextInput name="mk4" id={4} value={mKeys[3]} />
                  </Grid.Column>
                  <Grid.Column width={2}>
                    <TextInput name="mk1Num" type="number" />
                    <TextInput name="mk2Num" type="number" />
                    <TextInput name="mk3Num" type="number" />
                    <TextInput name="mk4Num" type="number" />
                  </Grid.Column>
                </Grid>
              )}

              {errors.err && (
                <Label
                  basic
                  color="red"
                  style={{ marginBottom: 10 }}
                  content={errors.err}
                />
              )}
              <br />
              <Button
                loading={isSubmitting}
                disabled={!isValid || isSubmitting}
                type="submit"
                fluidsize="large"
                color="teal"
                content="Submit"
                onClick={submitForm}
              />
            </Form>
          )}
        </Formik>
)
```

Till yesterday, setting the name property in the TextArea and TextInput, the same as the field in the initialValues object was enough to display the initital values. But i dont know what happened, the initial values are not showing up, although when i log them, they have correct values.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: `isSubmitting, submitForm, isValid, errors, values` <- add values , and use in TextInput as `value={values.mk3}`

Answer (score 3):

Try adding `enableReinitialize` to `Formik`.

```
<Formik
  enableReinitialize
  ...
```

You may have a case where the `initialValues` values get updated only after the first render.
On the first render `Formik` takes the `initialValues` as they are, so if the values didn't get updated yet you will not see them in the form fields.

SOURCE:
https://formik.org/docs/api/formik#enablereinitialize-boolean

Comment: I tried adding that, but didnt make a difference

Comment: You said that yesterday it was working.. What changed? Aren't you using some source control system (like git) to track changes?

Comment: the only thing that changed was the source of the data. I switch from firebase to an api of my own. I have source control. Let me see if i can find any major changes in the Formik part of the code, but i dont think there are any.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar issue where my problem was from the fact that my value wasn't a string, and the form input required a string as its input value.

To verify this, I examined the values object in the Formik context and observed that it was indeed being registered.

The solution was straightforward — I just needed to typecast the value to a string. Fortunately, most data types support the .toString() method, including string data types.

To resolve your issue, replace values={values.mk3} with values={values.mk3.toString()}. This adjustment should address the problem.